# Выбрать 10 случайных, уникальных записей из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Мне представляется, что это нужно реализовывать через `multi_query`. Код работает, но пока не проверяет на уникальность.

Может есть более лаконичные варианты такой выборки?
или
Подскажите генерацию уникальных `rand'ов`!

```
// запрашиваем суммарное кол-во записей в БД
    $query = "
              SELECT
                    COUNT(id)
              FROM
                    files
              WHERE
                    status = 1
             ";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        if ($row[0])
        {
                        $query = "
                            SELECT
                                  *
                            FROM
                                  files
                            WHERE
                                  status = 1
                                      AND
                                  id = " . rand(1, $row[0]) . ";";
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++)
            {
// присоединяем последующие запросы для функции multi_query
                $query .= "
                            SELECT
                                  *
                            FROM
                                  files
                            WHERE
                                  status = 1
                                      AND
                                  id = " . rand(1, $row[0]) . ($i < 10 ? ';' : '');
// добавляем ; во все строки кроме последней (проверка $i < 10)
            }

            if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
                do {

                    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
                        }
                        $result->free();
                    }

                    if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
                        printf("<br>\n");
                    }
                } while ($mysqli->next_result());
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Читаем http://habrahabr.ru/post/54176/

Comment: @Visman читал, разве использование UNION лучший вариант из возможных? Судя по статье ORDER BY RAND() тоже не подходит.

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужна [случайная выборка](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM files WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY rand();
```

Comment: Тормозить будет.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую к прочтению эту [статью](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).
В вашем случае будет так:

```
SELECT id FROM files AS f1 JOIN
    (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM files)) AS id) AS f2
WHERE f1.id >= f2.id
ORDER BY f1.id ASC
LIMIT 10;
```